# Open Safari from in app Links - Cordova PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, phonegap-plugins

I have a mobile app that works great minus one thing. I have a couple links that really need to go out of the webapp and open Safari to handle the content with the "Back to..." app at the top left. But no matter what I try including target="blank" ("_system", etc). All open within the app and I lose all control of the app and any navigation. I need these few links to jump out of the app and open Safari.

Can this be done outside the app on the web side or only internal?  How do I pop the safari open???

Comment: Have you added the Cordova In App Browser plugin to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [InAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). Verify its installed correctly and then call it within your deviceready handler like so:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://yoursite.com', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Answer (score -1):

The [OpenUrlExt](https://github.com/PaoloMessina/OpenUrlExt) plugin should make the native system call for you:

> Open a specific URL in the external browser of the hosting OS.
>
> cordova plugin add https://github.com/PaoloMessina/OpenUrlExt